# onClick event only leaves the last item of the DOM array instead of removing the target

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, target

```
class ToDo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      inputValue: null
    }
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this)
    this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this)
    this.removeTodo = this.removeTodo.bind(this)
  }

  changeValue(e) {
    this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value})
  }

  addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const newTodoItem = {
      id: Date.now(),
      inputValue: this.state.inputValue
    }

    if(!this.state.inputValue.length) return

    this.setState(state => ({
      todos: state.todos.concat(newTodoItem),
      inputValue: ''
    }))
  }

  removeTodo(e) {
    const et = e.target
    const todos = this.state.todos

    this.setState({
      todos: todos.splice(todos.indexOf(et), 1)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.addTodo}>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='todo'
            placeholder='Enter a ToDo'
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            onChange={this.changeValue}
          />
          <input type='submit' value='Add' />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span>ToDos: {this.state.todos.length}</span>
        </form>
        <TodoList items={this.state.todos} itemClickEvent={this.removeTodo} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const items = this.props.items
    return(
      <ul>
        {
          items.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id} onClick={this.props.itemClickEvent}>{item.inputValue}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToDo />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

In this todo list sample that I just imitated from the sample in the [reactjs.org](http://reactjs.org) homepage, I added an event that removes the targeted todo item when clicked. The problem is, whichever of the todo items I click, instead of removing the target item itself, it removes all the items except the last item. Why such bug is happening?

Comment: can you console.log todos.indexOf(et) on removeTodo?

Comment: it logs `-1` for every item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to make a few changes to make this work properly:

- Use `filter` instead of `splice`, as `filter` returns a **new** array as opposed to modifying the existing array. It's best practice to avoid modifying the existing state.
- Instead of grabbing `todos` before `setState`, use the variation of `setState` that passes the current state as the first parameter to a function in `setState`.
- Add a unique identifier to the `li` items that you can reference in your `removeTodo` function. Right now, `todos.splice(todos.indexOf(et), 1);` will not return anything meaningful, as `et` is an `Element`, and `todos` is not an array of `Element`s -- it is an array of Objects that have two keys: `id` and `inputValue`. What you can do instead is add a `data-key` attribute to your `li` that equals the `key` attribute, and then reference `data-key` in your `removeTodo`.

When you put it all together, this is the change you make to the JSX returned by the `TodoList` class:

```
items.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id} data-key={item.id} onClick={this.props.itemClickEvent}>{item.inputValue}</li>
))
```

Notice that we set `data-key` equal to `item.id`.

Our modified `removeTodo` will look like this:

```
removeTodo(e) {
    const et = e.target
    const attr = et.getAttribute("data-key");

    this.setState(state => ({
      todos: state.todos.filter(item => item.id != attr)
    }))
}
```

I've modified your [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/81w35p1g/) with a working example.

**Edit:**

Although the solution above works just fine, there's an alternative solution that is shorter and avoids having to add a `data-key` attribute to the `input`s:

Pass the `item.id` directly to `removeTodo` by making this change:

```
items.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id} onClick={() => this.props.itemClickEvent(item.id)}>{item.inputValue}</li>
))
```

Then, simplify your `removeTodo` to work by using its `id` parameter:

```
removeTodo(id) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      todos: state.todos.filter(item => item.id != id)
    }))
 }
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/e3z5pbhq/) with the new solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have one question... What makes a `setState` with function that returns an object different from regular `setState`?

Comment: The function that returns the new state is formally known as the `updater`, and you should always use it if your new state depends on your old sate (in your example, your new state depends on your old state's `todos`) because that is the only place that you are guaranteed to have an up-to-date `state` object. Theoretically speaking, if you grab your `state` before you call `setState()`, your state could be out-of-date (modified by some other function) by the time `setState()` runs. From docs: "If the next state depends on the previous state, we recommend using the updater function form"

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, Try this:

```
removeTodo(e) {
    const et = e.target
    const todos = this.state.todos
    todos.splice(todos.indexOf(et), 1);
    this.setState({
      todos
    })
}
```

**splice() return:**

> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is
>   removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
>   removed, an empty array is returned.